# How to deploy private app in play store

Tags: android, google-play

Hi i Developed Android App for Private company i wish to deploy it in playstore.But allow only an authorized persons to download the app rather than all users.Thanks in advance

Comment: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your client company is using Google Apps then Play store private channel can be helpful for you.

Go through below links

https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2623322?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

There is something like this provided by google for companies. Have a look at this link : https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992